# How to render a bitmap in NDK using OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, eclipse, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0

OS: Windows 7 
SDK: adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130717 
NDK: android-ndk-r8e 
Eclipse ADT: Build: v22.0.4-741630

I'm trying to render a bitmap using OpenGL ES in JNI. I have these headers declared at the top of the file:

```
#include <android/bitmap.h>
#include <GLES2/gl2.h>
```

so I don't understand why tokens such as GL_TEXTURE_2D are reported as "could not be resolved" and the project doesn't build. The frustrating part is that functions and variables defined in bitmap.h such as AndroidBitmap_getInfo() and ANDROID_BITMAP_FORMAT_RGB_565 don't cause a problem; they resolve properly.

The C/C++>General>Paths and Symbols properties for the project has this path:
C:\Android\android-ndk-r8e-windows-x86\android-ndk-r8e\platforms\android-9\arch-arm\usr\include

I see the tree structure in the header node of the Eclipse project and I've confirmed that android & GLES2 folders exist at that path location and each contain the appropriate .h file (bitmap.h and gl2.h respectively). How can it be that bitmap.h resolves but gl2.h doesn't? I'm declaring the includes exactly the same way!

Application.mk:

APP_PLATFORM := android-10
APP_ABI := armeabi-v7a
Any troubleshooting tips?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the failing line of code and the full compiler error message?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever tried the sample code bitmap-plasma & hello-gl2 in NDK package? you can check relevant Android.mk. make sure you have linked correct libraries

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := libgl2jni
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Werror
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := gl_code.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog -lGLESv2 -lm -ljnigraphics

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```